# Regex that can handle an arbitrary number of asterisks in a word

Tags: regex, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to write a regex for x509 CN/SAN validation and have just learned that apparently partial wildcards are possible in theory. How would I build a regex to handle this when I want to make sure that it captures all certificates that might be issued for `example.org`?

My naive approach would be

```
\**e\**x\**a\**m\**p\**l\**e\**.\**o\**r\**g\**
```

not including possible subdomains of course. This looks pretty bad though and really inflates the term longer than I'd like it to be. Is there a more concise way to get the behaviour I described?

Edit: I also just realised that my naive regex wouldn't even catch when someone uses the asterisk to replace a part of the domain, e.g. exa*.org.

Comment: Partials are poorly supported, but the documentation only references it as being possible to have as the last character before the `.`.  So something like `(?:(?:e(?:x(?:a(?:m(?:p(?:l(?:e)?)?)?)?)?)?)?\*|example).org`

Comment: According to RFC6125 section 6.4.3 rule 3: The client MAY match a presented identifier in which the wildcard character is not the only character of the label (e.g., baz*.example.net and *baz.example.net and b*z.example.net would be taken to match baz1.example.net and foobaz.example.net and buzz.example.net, respectively).

This means that (at least according to the RFC) the asterisk may appear anywhere in the left-most label of the domain.

Comment: yes, but there’s no example of `b*z.example.net`, so it’s unclear that any implementation would support it.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I got got by the SO comment markup, the last one is actually supposed to be b*z.example.net, SO just converted my asterisks to italics. So the RFC explicitly allows the asterisk in the middle unfortunately

Comment: So there is. It’s still not something that a public CA would do, the CA/Browser forum only allows it as the entirety of the leftmost label. I, personally, don’t know of a regex pattern other than all possible alternations, to match a candidate wildcard.

Comment: While it is true that no normal CA would do something like that, the regex I'm trying to build is supposed to be part of a CT log monitoring tool that must also protect against rogue or compromised CAs

Answer (score 0):

Since I feel like there's a possibility that this is not easily expressible in a concise regex, I solved my use case within the Python code that surrounds my previous regex check.

Instead of mapping a regex to the domains appearing in a certificate, I instead convert the certificate domain into a regex pattern, replace the literal dots with escaped dots and the asterisk with `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,63}`. I then compare it to the list of domains I manage and if the regex matches, I know that the certificate is applicable to the managed domain.

If someone manages to express this in a concise regex I'd still be interested.